# Network analysis: Formal definition of the number of 1st order neighbours of degree 1

Tags: mathematical-statistics, graph-theory, networks

I am looking for a formal definition of a network metric I am using in a scientific article. Let $i$ be a vertex in a graph $G$ and $N(i)$ are the first order neighbors of vertex $i$. I am interested in the number of 1st order neighbors of degree 1 (i.e. neighbors only connected to the vertex $i$).

To remain consistent with the rest of the article, I used the vertical bar (i.e. $|$) to identify the cardinality of a set of vertices.

**Edition**: The graph is *undirected* meaning that the edges do not have a direction. For two connected vertices $i$ and $j$, $(i,j)$ is equivalent to $(j,i)$. There is also no self-edges $(i,i)$.

Comment: That sounds like a formal definition to me, assuming you have already defined "degree" and "first order neighbors" somewhere.  (What distinction do you make between *adjacent vertices* and "first order neighbors"?)  It's even pretty safe to assume readers understand what "degree" means in this context because it's such a widely known basic concept in graph theory.  So, wouldn't "$|N(i)|$" be perfectly fine?  If you need anything even *more* formal, then please tell us whether your graph is directed or not.

Comment: Isn't $\vert N(i)\vert$ the total number of neighbors of point $i$ and not just the number of neighbors of $i$ who have no other neighbors?

Comment: @Dave In the question, $N(i)$ has been explicitly characterized as the set of "first order neighbors," not all neighbors.  Because "first order" and "neighbor" are redundant terms, I took "first order" to mean the neighbors of degree $1,$ but evidently that was wrong: your interpretation looks like the intended one.

Comment: @Whuber _First order neighbors_ is similar to _adjacent vertices_

Comment: @Dave $|N(i)$ is indeed the number of neighbors of vertex $i$ and not the number of neighbors who have no other neighbors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *graph* $\Gamma$ is an ordered pair $(V,E)$ where $V$ (the vertices) is any set and $E\subset V\times V$ (the edges) is a collection of ordered pairs of vertices.  We usually depict the vertices with point symbols at distinct locations in the plane and the edges $(v,w)$ as arrows running from the location of $v$ (the origin) to the location of $w$ (the destination).  Here is an example:

[image: Figure illustrating a graph with various kinds of degree-1 neighbors]

*All vertices in this plot are distinct and distinguished by color.  The edge colors correspond to their origins.  Loops are used (without arrowheads) to depict edges connecting a vertex with itself.*

To facilitate talking about graphs, let's think of any edge as "pointing" from its origin to its destination.

**Generally, there are two kinds of neighbors of any vertex $v\in V$:** the "inward pointing" neighbors $w$ for which $(w,v)\in E$ and the "outward pointing" neighbors for which $(v,w)\in E.$  In the figure, $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_8,$ and $w_9$ (roughly to the right of $v$) are inward-pointing neighbors of $v$ while $w_3,w_4,w_5,w_6,$ and $w_7$ (roughly to the left of $v$) are outward-pointing neighbors.  Notice that $w_3$ is both kinds of neighbor.

Thus, the inward-pointing neighbors of $v$ are the set

$$N_i(v) = \{w\in V\mid (w,v)\in E\}$$

and, likewise, the outward-pointing neighbors are

$$N_o(v) = \{w\in V\mid (v,w)\in E\}.$$

The union of these sets may be written

$$N(v) = N_i(v)\cup N_o(v),$$

the set of all vertices connected (in either direction or both) to $v.$

**From these definitions arise at least *nine* possible meanings of "first order neighbor of degree 1."**  Examples are

- $w_8$ is an inward-pointing neighbor of $v$ and the only neighbor of $w_8$ is $v.$  Thus, $$w_8\in N_i(v) \text{ and }\{v\} = N(w_8).$$
- $w_9$ is an inward-pointing neighbor of $v$ and $v$ is the only outward-pointing neighbor of $w_9$ distinct from $w_9$ itself.  Thus, $$w_9 \in N_i(v) \text{ and }\{v\} = N_o(w_9) \setminus\{w_9\}.$$
- $w_1$ is an inward-pointing neighbor of $v$ and $w_1$ itself has no inward-pointing neighbors.  Thus, $$w_1 \in N_i(v) \text{ and }N_i(w_1) = \emptyset.$$
- $w_2$ is an inward-pointing neighbor of $v$ and $v$ is the only outward-pointing neighbor of $w_2.$  Thus, $$w_2 \in N_i(v) \text{ and }\{v\} = N_o(w_2).$$
- $w_3$ is an inward-pointing neighbor of $v$ and $v$ is the only outward-pointing neighbor of $w_3.$  Thus, $$w_3 \in N_i(v) \text{ and }\{v\} = N_i(w_3).$$  Equivalently, $$w_3 \in N_o(v) \text{ and }\{v\} = N_o(w_3).$$

The relationships between $v$ and the other $w_j$ (which are outward-pointing neighbors of $v$) can be similarly expressed.  Notice that the concept of degree is not needed to define these relationships.

Thus, for instance, if $w_3$ exemplifies the kind of relationship you mean, then the quantity in the expression can be expressed as

> $$|\{w\in N_i(v) \mid \{v\} = N(w)\}|.$$

This involves two (implicit) subscripts: the "i" in the first $N_i(v)$ and the "" (no subscript) in the second $N(w).$  By choosing how to subscript these two expressions, you obtain many of the possible answers to the question.  By adding conditions on self-edges, you obtain a few more possible answers.

---

For *undirected graphs* (where the edges $(v,w)$ and $(w,v)$ are considered equivalent and therefore may be represented by the *set* $\{v,w\}$) and for graphs without self-edges $\{v,v\}=\{v\},$ the possibilities are fewer and the definitions simplify.  All three concepts of neighborhoods coincide with $$N(v) = \{w\in V\mid \{w,v\}\in E\}$$ and now the numbers of neighbors of degree $1$--including any self-edges--can be characterized as

> $$|\{w\in N(v)\mid \{v\}=N(w)\}|.$$

[image: Figure showing possible types of neighbors in an undirected graph]

In this figure, that would include neighbors like $w_1$ but not $w_2.$  Where self-edges are not included in the definition of $N(v),$ it would also include $w_2.$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I should have specified in my question that I am working with _undirected graphs_ without _self edges_. I have edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Thank you: that was the clarification I requested in the first comment to your question.  In the meantime I elected to answer the more difficult interpretation (of directed graphs with self edges), because--as my final remarks indicate--the same considerations apply to undirected graphs but the results are simpler.

Comment: I saw that. Thanks for the detailed answer, it's gonna be useful for future works. I'll be more clear next time I'll post a question.